# How can there be 2 X が in this sentence?

Tags: particle-が, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

This sentence is an excerpt from https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012813311000/k10012813311000.html

京都大学の西浦博教授は、東京都でこれから新しいコロナウイルス**が**うつる人**が**どのように変わるか計算しました。

Is my understanding correct?

1. うつる人が is the subject of the intransitive verb 変わる, so it must take が
2. 新しいコロナウイルスが is the subject of the relative clause, and so it also must take が?

So essentially this sentence can be loosely translated as: Professor Hiroshi Nishiura from Kyoto University has calculated how people who will become infected with new corona virus will change in Tokyo from now on?

:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nested clauses, and that's why there are two が's. To break down:

- 新しいコロナウイルスは人にうつる。
  The novel coronavirus infects people.
  <sub>(Note that うつる is an intransitive verb in Japanese)</sub>
- 新しいコロナウイルスがうつる人
  people which the novel coronavirus infects
  <sub>(Simple relative clause)</sub>

  → people infected by the novel coronavirus
- 新しいコロナウイルスがうつる人(の数)がどのように変わるか
  how the (number of) people infected by the novel coronavirus changes

Judging from the remaining part of the article, this sentence is clearly about the change in **the number of** (infected) people, not the change of people themselves. I don't know why the text said 人がどのように変わるか ("how people changes") instead of 人の数がどのように変わるか ("how the number of people changes"). Sometimes this "easy" news from NHK omits words a little too aggressively...

Comment: Hey Naruto, I actually did interpret it as "the number of people" (I guess my brain just filled in the gaps). The one thing I do worry about with these easy NHK articles is that it really isn't natural at all, but I think the original articles are too complicated for me at the moment :s Bit of a catch 22.